# For Apple Watch OS in Swift, how can I have a function run after WCSession activation is complete?

Tags: swift, communication, apple-watch, wcsession

I have a method in my main interface controller class that I wish to run when the WCSession between the phone and watch has finished activating. I know there is a didFinishActivation function in the WCSession class. However, how do I communicate the result of this function to my main interface controller class to run the function in there, after WCSession has finished activating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your interface controller class conform to the `WCSessionDelegate` protocol and then the `session(_:activationDidCompleteWith:error:)` function will be automatically called once the `WCSession` is activated.